# Kill specific function called by IpcMain Electron

Tags: javascript, electron

I am new to Javascript and Electron.

Lets say I got 10 pair of buttons. Each pair of button consist of a 'Start' and a 'Cancel' button. Each 'Start' button can call a same function that import from another JS script when clicked.

So, if I had pressed the first and third 'Start' button, the same function will be called twice.

Now, I want to kill the function that called by the third 'Start' button only by clicking the third 'Cancel' button. Is there any way to resolve this?

Below is a simplified code that I had wrote:

```
const hi = require('helloworld.js')

ipcMain.on("runFunction", (event, data) => {
   hi()
});

ipcMain.on("killFunction", (event, data) => {
  // What I should write here
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the ipc.on to work you should actually send an event(specifically runFunction event according to your code) when button is clicked. so this triggers the event and ipcMain.on() will be working as the event is triggered.

Now you can actually pass data while sending an event.so using ipc.send() , here you can pass the index of start button and use this index accordingly to kill.

Example : `ipcRenderer.send('asynchronous-message', 'ping')`

Refer this for code examples
https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main